# Retrieving number of distinct values in Parse?

Tags: parse-platform

Is there any Parse equivalent to the SQL statement, `SELECT DISTINCT`?

I have the tables: *User*, *Group*, *Tag*, and *Post*. Each user has posts and can create tags and groups. The *Tag* table contains the fields:

`"name" String`

`"post" Pointer<Post>`

`"creator" Pointer<_User>`

I am trying to make a cloud function to return the most popular tags to my Android app for an AutoCompleteTextView. I was thinking that I should just do something like a `SELECT DISTINCT name` query in Parse and order by descending, but you can't do that in Parse. Is there any workaround for this?

I saw that [this post](https://parse.com/questions/select-distinct-equivalent) did not get an answer and that [this post](https://parse.com/questions/retrieving-unique-values) says to work out distinct values client-side.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not implemented yet, check this answer on Parse.com, which you've mentioned it too:

https://parse.com/questions/retrieving-unique-values

The answer in following post is actually means: read all rows, select unique ones :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I saw [this post](https://parse.com/questions/fetch-all-data-in-a-table-using-pfquery) suggesting that that to fetch all the data from a table, you could query 1000 objects at a time. This seems very computationally expensive. Is this the way to do read all the rows and select the unique ones? or should I have a counter field somewhere in my DB showing the most popular tags (having a Pointer<Tag> field)?

Comment: @lschessinger Yes query is limited and expensive, but generally parse.com is not designed for this sort of job. Try some cloud server or sql service.

Comment: Currently you can use 'uniq' function from Underscore library, bit it will be bit expensive on query.